# How to see Podman Desktop logs in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, podman

I tried to install Podman Desktop (4.5.1) for restricted environment, as mentioned in [here](https://podman-desktop.io/docs/Installation/windows-install/installing-podman-desktop-and-podman-in-a-restricted-environment). When I try to click `Initialize and start` button in Podman Desktop, it stucks. I cannot see what kind of error I am getting. Is there any log file that I can follow? Actually, I realized that `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Podman Desktop` folder has info about Podman, but could not find any readable stuff. As well, I tried to delete that folder to have a clean setup, but nothing has changed.